# ld: library not found for -lboost_python

Tags: python, boost, homebrew, boost-python

I install boost using `brew install --build-from-source --with-python --fresh -vd boost`. Yet when I run `make pycaffe` in the Caffe project, I get this error: `ld: library not found for -lboost_python`. How can I install that library? `find / -name libboost_python*`  turns up nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Run the command `brew install boost-python` This will download, compile, and install the boost package with boost-python support. boost-python is required for the graphicsmagick-engine pip package and I ran into the same issue. To give you an idea of what happens, this is the output from the command:

```
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.57.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.57.0/lib --with-libraries=python --with-python=python --with-python-root=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
==> ./b2 --build-dir=build-python --stagedir=stage-python python=2.7 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.57.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.57.0/lib -d2 -j8 --layout=tagged --user-config=user-config.jam threading=multi,s
```

You could alternatively download, compile, and symlink the boost package (which is what I did originally) but this is a whole lot simpler if the default paths work for you.

Comment: For python3, you need to run `brew install boost-python --with-python3`, and then build using `-lboost_python3`

Comment: @ronen, but what if `-lboost_python3 not found`? How to fix it, I came across this issue.

Comment: Try using `brew install boost-python3` – the syntax may have changed.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out boost 1.56 seems to have issues with NVCC, so the boost_python lib files don't get installed. Installing using boost 1.55 works. I used:

```
git checkout a252214 /usr/local/Library/Formula/boost.rb
brew install --build-from-source --with-python --fresh -vd boost
```

Thanks to [this thread](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1193)

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble installing caffe on OS X 10.9.5.  Did you install it with the modified brew formulaes?  It seems like I get a different error every time I try to compile caffe.  I am getting not being able to find files or BLAS (even though Mac has it installed via Accelerate).  Any tips?

Comment: Yes, make sure you do the `brew edit` step. Follow the Caffe instructions closely. I installed OpenBLAS.

Comment: Although Caffe compliation succeeds, I still get `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread` when I try to run Caffe. Please let me know if you do too! Homebrew's advice on this problem doesn't seem helpful: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues. I'm working through `brew doctor` issues before posting an issue.

Comment: After using boost 1.55, it compiled but wouldn't execute, like you found out. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

For me, there is no such `libboost_python37.dylib` in boost-python lib path

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0_1/lib
libboost_numpy37-mt.a      libboost_numpy37.a         libboost_python37-mt.dylib libboost_python37.dylib
libboost_numpy37-mt.dylib  libboost_numpy37.dylib     libboost_python37-mt.a     libboost_python37.a
```

So create a soft link

```
$ sudo ln -s libboost_python37.dylib libboost_python3.dylib
```

This problem is fixed.

Similar question: [ld: library not found for -lboost_python on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906096/ld-library-not-found-for-lboost-python-on-macos)