# Is this Boost::Python (Python 3.7) error "__init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'" a linking problem?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

## Update

I'm not going to add this as an answer, since I still haven't technically solved the problem. But since I've now spent 2.5 days trying to get things to work with boost-python3, I've lost the will to live with it.

I've just come across [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) (how my previous lengthy searches for python binding tools didn't turn it up, I don't know) and am using that. 2.5 days of misery compares to <20 minutes installing and building their [cmake example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example)... and all the specific-python-version-dependency-hell is gone.

It's syntactically similar to boost-python but much easier to manage, quicker, is header-only and is more feature rich.

Yay!

## Original question

I'm using boost::python to bind a class in python 3.7.2.

The class import successfully but instantiating it gives the following error:

```
<my-terminal>$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 14 2019, 17:36:47) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import classes
>>> t = classes.World()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
>>>
```

Here is `classes.cpp`:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { mMsg = msg; }
    void many(boost::python::list msgs) {
        long l = len(msgs);
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (long i = 0; i<l; ++i) {
            if (i>0) ss << ", ";
            std::string s = boost::python::extract<std::string>(msgs[i]);
            ss << s;
        }
        mMsg = ss.str();
    }
    std::string greet() { return mMsg; }
    std::string mMsg;
};

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(classes)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
        .def("many", &World::many)
    ;
};
```

### Hypothesis

[This question, almost identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437769/boost-python-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype) was solved because of a python 2/3 issue (linking against python 3 instead of python 2 libraries). So I suspected a library linking issue.

#### Checking the hypothesis

I can't get bjam to work, and wouldn't be able to switch all our build systems over for one module anyway... so am building with cmake, which compiles successfully to `classes.so` with output as follows, suggesting I'm finding all the correct includes, libraries and executables:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/boost37/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.7.2", minimum required is "3") 
PYTHON_VERSION_SUFFIX
-- Boost version: 1.68.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python37
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib (found suitable version "3.7.2", minimum required is "3") 
-- PYTHON_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
-- PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = /Users/thc29/.pyenv/versions/boost37/bin/python3
-- PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
-- Boost_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/lib/libboost_python37-mt.dylib
```

Boost-python3 library directory contents:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.68.0/lib
libboost_numpy37-mt.a       libboost_numpy37.dylib      libboost_python37.a
libboost_numpy37-mt.dylib   libboost_python37-mt.a      libboost_python37.dylib
libboost_numpy37.a      libboost_python37-mt.dylib
```

I used `brew install boost`, and `brew install boost-python3 --build-from-source` with my python 3.7 virtualenv activated, to ensure boost-python3 is linked against the correct version of python.

Checking libraries...

`otool -L classes.so` gives:

```
classes.so:
    /usr/l/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python37-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python (compatibility version 3.7.0, current version 3.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

`otool -L  /usr/local/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python37-mt.dylib` gives:

```
/usr/local/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python37-mt.dylib:
        /usr/local/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python37-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
```

In the related question, that showed their problem. But here it appears fine!

### No progress yet...

After the painful process of getting this all compiling properly and checking the linking, I can't spot any flaws. Is this a different problem? Or is there a linking issue that I haven't spotted?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am following a [similar example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html) and I adopt the Makefile from [here](https://pyengr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/inter/bpy/index.html#create-a-python-extension). I have installed `python 3.7.4` and `boost-python` via `brew` on `macOS`. To fix the `NoneType` issue, I follow the procedure below:

**1. Check the `Python` Path**
To check the `python` path, use

```
which python
```

If the output does not look like the following one (`brew`'s `python` installation path)

```
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
```

set the `PATH` variable as

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Check if the `Python` path looks like the one above again.

**2. Check the Compilation Flag**
Below is the adopted `Makefile`. Note the `LIB` variable. If the `boost-python` flag is `-lboost_python`, change it to `-lboost_python37`.

```
CPP = clang++
PYLIBPATH = $(shell python-config --exec-prefix)/lib
# LIB = -L$(PYLIBPATH) $(shell python-config --libs) -lboost_python
LIB = -L$(PYLIBPATH) $(shell python-config --libs) -lboost_python37
OPTS = $(shell python-config --include) -O2

default: hello.so


hello.so: hello.o
    $(CPP) $(LIB) -Wl,-rpath,$(PYLIBPATH) -shared $< -o $@

hello.o: hello.cpp Makefile
    $(CPP) $(OPTS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.so *.o

.PHONY: default clean
```

Recompile the `C++` code and run the `python` script. The `NoneType` issue should disappear.

Hope this helps.

**Note**
If you are using `anaconda` and want to restore the `PATH` variable after the above changes, try

```
export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Your `anaconda`'s path may be different.

**Credit**
1. **George**'s comment in [How do I use brew installed Python as the default Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157678/how-do-i-use-brew-installed-python-as-the-default-python)
2. **leiyc**'s comment in [ld: library not found for -lboost_python on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906096/ld-library-not-found-for-lboost-python-on-macos)

Comment: Thanks Nick, this *looks* like it'll solve the issue, so I'll accept on trust, even though I can't test (long since moved to pybind, per the update in the question). Thanks for a really good explanation answer too.

Answer (score 5):

Adding an answer here for those using the Anaconda or Conda-Forge Distribution:

The python interpreter statically links in the `libpythonXY` library. Which is why it makes the python binary different compared to other distributions.

The fix for the problem reported by OP is to use:

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup
```

Instead of:

```
-lpythonXY
```

You are creating a Python C/C++ extension, and not embedding the python interpreter. So you shouldn't be linking to the python library. Pybind11 handles this correctly.

See the following for more information:

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18100
- https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9078

One a side note, python 3.8 has added an additional flag: `--embed` and only then it adds `-lpythonXY` in the output:

```
$ python3.8-config --libs
-ldl -framework CoreFoundation

$ python3.8-config --libs --embed
-lpython3.8 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - this has fixed my related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [Nehal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61592909/4249913) answer for Anaconda based builds. Rereading the FindPython documentation for cmake shows the [Python::Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#imported-targets) target was added in cmake 3.15 for creating modules.  That means the CMakeLists.txt should be:

```
set(Python3_FIND_VIRTUALENV FIRST)
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED Development)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3)
add_library(classes MODULE classes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(classes PRIVATE Python3::Module Boost::python3)
```

Apparently, the `Python3::Python` is for embedding Python in another application.